# Postgres complexe upsert

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have the following postgres upsert query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dm_insights_best_performing_format_view_two (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        platform VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        page_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        created_time DATE NOT NULL,
        post_class VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
        video_length VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
        total_impressions BIGINT NOT NULL,
        average_impressions DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
        total_views BIGINT NOT NULL,
        average_views DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
        nb_contenu INTEGER NOT NULL,
        _iat TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        _uat TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
      );
      
      ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dm_insights_best_performing_format_view_two
        DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS dm_insights_best_performing_format_view_two_page_id_date_platform_unique;
        
      ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dm_insights_best_performing_format_view_two
        ADD CONSTRAINT dm_insights_best_performing_format_view_two_page_id_date_platform_unique UNIQUE (page_id, platform, post_class, created_time);
      
      INSERT INTO dm_insights_best_performing_format_view_two (
        platform,
        page_id,
        created_time,
        post_class,
        video_length,
        total_impressions,
        average_impressions,
        total_views,
        average_views,
        nb_contenu
      )
      
      WITH fb_perf AS (
        SELECT
            fb_page_post_daily_insights.post_id,
            fb_page_post_daily_insights.impressions,
            fb_page_post_daily_insights.video_views,
                page_id,
                DATE(created_time) AS created_time,
            CASE
                WHEN fb_page_post_attachments.type = 'album' THEN 'Carousel'
                WHEN fb_page_post_attachments.type = 'photo' THEN 'Photo'
                WHEN fb_page_post_attachments.type = 'video' THEN 'Video'
                WHEN fb_page_post_attachments.type = 'video_inline' THEN 'Video'
                WHEN fb_page_post_attachments.type = 'video_direct_response' THEN 'Video'
                ELSE 'Autres'
            END AS media_type,
            CASE
                WHEN fb_page_post_attachments.video_length / 1000 <= 60 THEN '0-1 minutes'
                WHEN fb_page_post_attachments.video_length / 1000 <= 180 THEN '1-3 minutes'
                WHEN fb_page_post_attachments.video_length / 1000 > 180 THEN '3+ minutes'
                ELSE 'Autres'
            END AS video_length,
            CASE
                WHEN sponsor_id IS NULL THEN 'edito'
                ELSE 'brand-content'
            END AS post_class
        FROM
            fb_page_post_daily_insights
        INNER JOIN fb_page_post ON fb_page_post.id = fb_page_post_daily_insights.post_id
        LEFT JOIN fb_page_post_attachments ON fb_page_post_attachments.post_id = fb_page_post_daily_insights.post_id
        WHERE impressions > 0
    ),
    fb_clean AS (
        SELECT
            post_id,
            SUM(impressions) AS impressions,
            SUM(video_views) AS video_views,
            media_type,
            video_length,
            post_class,
              page_id,
              DATE(created_time) AS created_time
        FROM
            fb_perf
        GROUP BY
            post_id,
            post_class,
            media_type,
            video_length,
                page_id,
                DATE(created_time)
    )
    SELECT
        'facebook' AS platform,
        page_id,
        DATE(created_time) AS created_time,
        post_class,
        video_length,
        SUM(impressions) AS total_impressions,
        AVG(impressions) AS average_impressions,
        SUM(video_views) AS total_views,
        AVG(video_views) AS average_views,
        SUM(nb_content) AS nb_contenu
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                *,
                1 AS nb_content
            FROM
                fb_clean
        ) s
    GROUP BY
          page_id,
          DATE(created_time),
        post_class,
        video_length
        
     ON CONFLICT (platform, page_id, post_class, created_time)
        DO UPDATE SET   
        video_length = EXCLUDED.video_length,
        total_impressions = EXCLUDED.total_impressions,
        average_impressions = EXCLUDED.average_impressions,
        total_views = EXCLUDED.total_views,
        average_views = EXCLUDED.average_views,
        nb_contenu = EXCLUDED.nb_contenu;
```

However, this produces this error when launching the migration : `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time`

I searched around but did not found a working answer for my problem. I don't understand as I have a very similar query where the upsert works as intended. Could someone help me out ? Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update on conflict postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736332/how-to-update-on-conflict-postgres)